# Open internet page with id, password and valid button

Tags: vba, excel

I try to open this webpage. I can enter my id, my password but when I try to click on the login button that doesn't work
my code.

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
Dim ie As InternetExplorer
Dim IEdoc As Object
Dim DOCelement As Object

Set ie = New InternetExplorer
ie.Visible = True
ie.Navigate ("https://inds.epicinds.com/epic/login")

'attente de fin de chargement
Do Until ie.ReadyState = 4    
DoEvents
Loop
Set IEdoc = ie.Document

'login
Set DOCelement = IEdoc.getElementsByName("UserID_l").Item
DOCelement.Value = "xxxxxxx"

'password
Set DOCelement = IEdoc.getElementsByName("Password_l").Item
DOCelement.Value = "xxxxxx"

'connexion
Set DOCelement = IEdoc.forms(0)
DOCelement.submit
Do While ie.Busy Or ie.ReadyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE
DoEvents
Loop
End Sub
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Note that getElementsByName is plural; that is, it returns a collection even if there is only one element in that collection. Treat it as an array of elements with the same name and choose the first element.

```
...

'login
Set DOCelement = IEdoc.getElementsByName("UserID_l")(0)
DOCelement.Value = "xxxxxxx"

'password
Set DOCelement = IEdoc.getElementsByName("Password_l")(0)
DOCelement.Value = "xxxxxx"

...
```

You could also switch to the singular getElementbyId since the two log in credentials inputs share common names and IDs.

```
...

'login
Set DOCelement = IEdoc.getElementbyId("UserID_l")
DOCelement.Value = "xxxxxxx"

'password
Set DOCelement = IEdoc.getElementbyId("Password_l")
DOCelement.Value = "xxxxxx"

...
```

The form (identified by Id) only has a single anchor (<A>) element. The Login button is an image enclosed by this anchor tag.

```
IEdoc.getElementbyId("LoginForm").getElementsByTagName("A")(0).Click
```

Answer (score 0):

Other syntax is as follows where an ID, `#`, CSS selector is used to target the entry fields by their id. The login button can be targeted by its attribute `alt` whose value is `Login` i.e. `[alt=Login`], where `[]` is the attribute selector.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub EnterInfo()
    Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
    With IE
        .Visible = True
        .navigate "https://inds.epicinds.com/epic/login"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend
        With .document
            .querySelector("#UserID_l").innerText = "Joe.Bloggs@email.com"
            .querySelector("#Password_l").innerText = "mySecretPassword"
            .querySelector("[alt=Login]").Click
        End With
        Stop   '<=delete me after
        'other stuff
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```